# Parent click handler is always executing first

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a simple list:

```
<li onClick={handleRowClick}>
 <input type="checkbox" onClick={handleCheckboxClick} />
 ...
</li>
```

When I click in any place on the `li` (except its checkbox child), `handleRowClick` executes.

When I click on the `checkbox`, it **always** executes in this order:

```
row
row
checkbox
```

#### Here's what I've tried

1. using `onClickCapture` on each: checkbox, li, and both
2. calling `e.stopPropagation()` on each: checkbox, li, and both
3. calling `e.nativeEvent.stopPropagation()` on each: checkbox, li, and both
4. calling `e.nativeEvent.stopImmediatePropagation()` on each: checkbox, li, and both
5. calling `e.nativeEvent.preventDefault()` on each: checkbox, li, and both

With the code above, at some point the order became

```
row
checkbox
```

But the `row` is always executed BEFORE the checkbox, so I can't see how make them not overlap.

**Also worth mentioning that both handlers have logic, that need to happen, so making the row never execute any code is not an option.**

This seems like a trivial thing, like I should know the answer to this. What am I missing?

#### Edit

Here's the minimal reproducible example: https://codesandbox.io/s/shy-shape-u1me4?file=/src/App.js

In the example above I stripped a lot of things like CSS classes. While doing that, I realised that what I'm actually clicking is a `label` for the checkbox, and the checkbox is "hidden" in my app.

I solved the problem by moving the event handler to the `label` instead of the checkbox, and running:

1. `e.stopPropagation()` to prevent propagation to the parent `li`.
2. `e.preventDefault()` to prevent the label to trigger the checkboxes o'clock, which would also cause the event to propagate to the `li` above.

Comment: I guess there must be something special about react’s event handling, because this doesn’t happen with vanilla JS - https://jsfiddle.net/xjvoh4zc/ Maybe react does not actually add a click handler for the checkbox element, but uses event delegation on the LI (or even further up)?

Comment: Hmm, good point. I'll try to get a sandbox running and link it

Comment: Works as expected: https://codepen.io/tilwinjoy/pen/mdRZebm?editors=0011 please create an [mcve] demonstrating the problem

Answer (score 0):

The problem seem to be that **my UI library hides the actual `input`, and the visible area where I was clicking was actually the `label`. These 2 elements are siblings** related by the `id` and `htmlFor` attributes respectively.

As I was attaching the event handler on the input, but the label was the one actually being clicked, the propagation was not properly being stopped.

I solved the problem by moving the event handler to the `label` instead of the checkbox, and running:

1. `e.stopPropagation()` to prevent propagation to the parent `li`.
2. `e.preventDefault()` to prevent the label to trigger the checkboxes o'clock, which would also cause the event to propagate to the `li` above.

```
<li onClick={handleRowClick}>
 <input id="c-1" type="checkbox" />
 <label htmlFor="c-1" onClick={handleCheckboxClick}>Foo</label>
 ...
</li>


const handleCheckboxClick = () => {
  e.stopPropagation()
  e.preventDefault()
}
```